# Custom ClientHttpRequestInterceptor null response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have my own implementation of `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`. In `intercept` method after invoke `ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body)` I want to process the response,
but the variable `response` is `null` when any error occurs or timeout.

However, later on when I catch `restTemplate` exception I'm able to read some information about the response like status code or even some error message.

Is it possible to get that information in `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` or any other interceptor?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If I understand correctly, you use your own `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` for `RestTemplate`? If yes, just add also own implementation of the `ResponseErrorHandler`:

```
...
var restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.setInterceptors(List.of(new OwnClientHttpRequestInterceptor()));
restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new OwnResponseErrorHandler());
...
```

In that case, you can make some covering actions with a request (usually it used for request because a response can be undefined) in the interceptor (for example, set header), and have 2 ways for response handling: after getting a response in base code or on error throwing in the error handler.